# How to serialise JSON with dynamic types

Tags: ios, json, swift, object, serialization

I need to serialise a JSON response of some what below type. which has different type

```
[{
 "type": "respiration_rate",
 "value": 45
}
{ "type": "blood_pressure",
 "value": { hg: 50 ,mm:120 }
}]
```

My class for serialising the upper json is

```
class Template: Codable {
   var type: String?
   var value: Double?
   private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type
        case value
    }
  }
```

How can serialise the `value` wether it be double or object dynamically?

Comment: Use `Any?` in place of `Double?` and convert to respected type at a later stage (while using that value)

Comment: Using `Any?` throwing `does not conform to protocol ` compile time error.

Comment: I would probably suggest you fall back to manual parsing so that you can create instances of appropriately typed structs

Comment: Do you only have these two options, `respiration_rate` thaty will have value `Double` and `blood_pressure` that will have an object?

Comment: Here i just posted an example of json. Till now i have done everything serilaization process. i have written lots of code. if choose to parse manually i need to change lots of code.   @Paulw11

Comment: Unfortunately your JSON is poorly designed. The best fix would be to have the server send properly structured data rather than variable data based on another key's value. Codable isn't going to be able to deal with this automatically.

Comment: @Ladislav  No! there are some more objects in array which all are in same format. except the `blood_pressure ` has `object` remaining everything are in `Double`

Comment: Then you could make it work with a wrapper type, i will post a solution once i get to my computer on an hour or so

Comment: @Ladislav How? can you please explain.

Comment: try https://app.quicktype.io/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you need:

```
class Template: Codable {
    let type: String?
    let value: Value?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type
        case value
    }

    typealias ValueDictionary = Dictionary<String, Int>
    enum Value: Codable {
        case double(Double)
        case object(ValueDictionary)

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
            if let x = try? container.decode(Double.self) {
                self = .double(x)
                return
            }
            if let x = try? container.decode(ValueDictionary.self) {
                self = .object(x)
                return
            }
            throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Value.self, DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath, debugDescription: "Wrong type for ValueUnion"))
        }

        func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
            var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
            switch self {
            case .double(let x):
                try container.encode(x)
            case .object(let x):
                try container.encode(x)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an enum with associated values instead of a class, as the JSON format seems be heterogenous.

```
enum Value: Decodable {
    case respirationRate(Double)
    case bloodPressure(hg: Double, mm: Double)

    private struct BloodPresure: Decodable {
        let hg: Double
        let mm: Double
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type
        case value
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        switch try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type) {
        case "respiration_rate":
            self = try .respirationRate(container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .value))
        case "blood_pressure":
            let details = try container.decode(BloodPresure.self, forKey: .value)
            self = .bloodPressure(hg: details.hg, mm: details.mm)
        case let type: throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .value, in: container, debugDescription: "Invalid type: \(type)")
        }
    }
}
```

Decoding your json is now easy:

```
let json = """
[{
"type": "respiration_rate",
"value": 45
},
{ "type": "blood_pressure",
"value": { "hg": 50 ,"mm":120 }
}]
"""

do {
    let values = try JSONDecoder().decode([Value].self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
    print(values)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```